# Cannot access base class' protected method in assignment operator

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, protected

I have a rather simple data structure, that is part of an interface. As such, the structure's base class is also an interface that does not define any data.

This structure may have different data implementations, but they all must be assignable from each other. This is simplified MCVE of the problem:

```
class ThingInterface {
  public:
    // Assignment operator required from the interface to all derived classes
    virtual void operator=(const ThingInterface& other) = 0;
  protected:
    virtual int GetValue() const = 0;
};

class ThingImplementation : public ThingInterface {
  public:
    void operator=(const ThingInterface& other) override { value = other.GetValue(); }
  protected:
    virtual int GetValue() const { return value; }
  private:
    int value;
};
```

The reason `GetValue` is protected is that in my actual code, that value describes internal state (Initialized, NotInitialized, Error...). It still needs to be copied though.

MSVC error:

```
error C2248: 'ThingInterface::GetValue': cannot access protected member declared in class 'ThingInterface'
note: see declaration of 'ThingInterface::GetType'
note: see declaration of 'ThingInterface'
```

Error seen on Ideone:

```
prog.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void ThingImplementation::operator=(const ThingInterface&)’:
prog.cpp:11:83: error: ‘virtual int ThingInterface::GetValue() const’ is protected within this context
     void operator=(const ThingInterface& other) override { value = other.GetValue(); }
                                                                                   ^
prog.cpp:6:17: note: declared protected here
     virtual int GetValue() const = 0;
                 ^~~~~~~~
```

I was under the implession that it's possible to access base class' `protected` members. What's going on here?

Comment: You can access your own base class protected members, but not members of other object which has type of base class. That's the short answer

Comment: What's the difference between private and protected then?

Comment: That private cannot be accessed even by the derived classes, that's all

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I can access `this->protectedMethod` but not `randomPointer->protectedMethod`. I fixed the problem by instead determining the state of the other object based on it's public interface behavior.

Comment: @TomášZato its not about the pointer, but the type of the pointer. Protected means that the class who inherits the member will be able to access that inherited member. Here you are trying to explicity access GetValue() on the original ThingInterface. It would work if other was of type ThingImplementation&

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this snippet:

```
void operator=(const ThingInterface& other) override { value = other.GetValue(); }
```

`protected` only applies to `this` here. In your case, accessing `GetValue()` from anywhere but `ThingInterface` through `other` is illegal. Clang has a nice error message that might make more sense:

> note: can only access this member on an object of type
>   '`ThingImplementation`'
>
> ```
> virtual int GetValue() const = 0;
>             ^
> ```